# Dynamic array formula for aggregation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have raw data in B3:C11. The formula of E3 is `=UNIQUE(B3:B11)`. In Column F, I would like to sum up the number in Column C for each person.

In F3, I tried `=SUM(FILTER($C$3:$C$11,E3=$B$3:$B$11))` and `=SUM((E3=$B$3:$B$11)*$C$3:$C$11)`, which all work for F3. But the formula `=SUM(FILTER($C$3:$C$11,E3#=$B$3:$B$11))` or `=SUM((E3#=$B$3:$B$11)*$C$3:$C$11)` failed.

Does anyone know how to write a spilled formula in F3 to fill in Column F?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `SUMIF` formula like below:

`=SUMIF($B$2:$B$11,E3,$C$2:$C$11)`

and copy down as much needed.

Comment: Thank you... I use `=SUMIF($B$2:$B$11,E3#,$C$2:$C$11)` in F3.